# How to put Default.png in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone

I have Default.png(480*320) image.My question is that when i start application then Default.png image is show in landscape mode.How it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why cannot you use already rotated picture with 320*480 resolution?)

Comment: If i am put Default.png image in resources folder then it will take as a splash screen.But how to rotate this image?

Comment: I mean that your image can be rotated before you include it in your project. You cannot modify this picture on flight, because your app is loading.

Answer (score 15):

First, pre-rotate your splash image so you have a portrait and landscape version.

Then, use `Default-Portrait.png` and `Default-Landscape.png` as image names.

`Default.png` only works with one image for both orientations.