# The Default.png of size 480x320 in landscape mode in iphone

Tags: iphone, orientation, default.png

I am developing an application that is in landscape mode. I have Default.png with size 480x320.
But still when it launches the default image comes in portrait mode not in landscape mode.

However it should come according to the device oreintation.

If i take default.png with same size in allready rotated. then it comes as it was in rotated mode.

However it should come according to the device oreintation.

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put Default.png in landscape mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973805/how-to-put-default-png-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to question [How to put Default.png in landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1973805/143) by @brentford that should help you.

There is also an [article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/defaultpng-and-landscape-mode.html) by John Muchow which outlines a different way one way to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Taken straight from here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

"In iOS 3.2 and later, an iPad application can provide different launch images depending on whether the device is in a portrait or landscape configuration. To specify a launch image for a different orientation, you must add a special modifier string to the base file name of your standard launch image. Thus, the format of each file name becomes the following:

`[basename][orientation_modifier][scale_modifier][device_modifier].png`"

So in your example you could have:

`Default-Landscape.png`

`Default-Portrait.png`

`(Default-Landscape@2x.png for iphone 4 and Default-Landscape~ipad.png for ipad and so forth...)`

both have to be 320x480 and you'll have to ensure that your app's `Info.plist` contains all 4 `UISupportedOrientation` values (UIOrientationPortrait, UIOrientationLandscapeLeft etc etc). But see my above link for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the splashscreen is loaded without checking for orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set UIInterfaceOrientation key in the info.plist file to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft (iPhone home button will be on the left) or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight (home button on right).

Answer (score 0):

See this post:

[How do I detect orientation on app launch for splash screen animation on iPad!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477582/how-do-i-detect-orientation-on-app-launch-for-splash-screen-animation-on-ipad)