# Landscape Orientation Home Button Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

while my landscape-only app is launching, it initially launches the load screen in "Landscape (left home button)" mode regardless if the home button is on the right. When it is finished launching, the app view controller appears in "Landscape (left home button)" mode briefly and then rotates to the correct orientation.  I have the supported interface orientations with "Landscape (left home button)" and "Landscape (right home button)" and also the supported device orientations selected properly.  I've noticed a few other apps doing this as well but most launch correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify: app launches with wrong orientation, but quickly switches to correct one? Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888016/ios-device-orientation-on-load) answer your question?

Comment: Your clarification is correct but I've tried those solutions to no avail.  The app launches in the incorrect orientation and quickly corrects itself as soon as the viewcontroller appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using Default-landscape.png (as opposed to just Default.png). See [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973805/how-to-put-default-png-in-landscape-mode)